# What is the difference between tx version 1 and RingCT version 2?

Tags: ringct

What were the changes from version 1 to version 2?

I think that version 1, did not have confidential txs, but was still based on cryptonote?

I'm also guessing that in version 1, we did not have these different signature types like RCTTypeSimple and RCTTypeNull.

I think we still had ring signatures but it was something called LSAG and Borromean signatures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-RingCT (tx version 1), the main difference is the amounts were not hidden. They still had a form of ring-signature, but no, there were no signature *types* like the RCTType... ones as found in RingCT transactions - because they were not RingCT transactions.

RingCT (tx version 2), generalized a new type of ring signature, LSAG, into an MLSAG signature and incorporated Confidential Transactions to hide the amounts. The original RingCT paper can be found [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/1098.pdf) which describes the changes and background.